# Buttons are missed in UITabBar swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, gradient

I have added a custom gradient layer to my tab bar to make it more user-friendly. but my tab bars buttons are under the gradient layer.
does anybody know whats wrong here?
[The UI image just to clarify what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvHty.jpg)

```
class TabBarUiViewController: UITabBarController {

   let layerGradient = CAGradientLayer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       layerGradient.colors = [UIColor.init(red: 247/255, green: 146/255, blue: 30/255, alpha: 1).cgColor, UIColor.init(red: 236/255, green: 104/255, blue: 66/255, alpha: 1).cgColor]
       layerGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
       layerGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
       layerGradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
       self.tabBar.layer.addSublayer(layerGradient)
    }
}
```

this is the whole code I found on the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
self.tabBar.layer.addSublayer(layerGradient)
```

with

```
self.tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(layerGradient,at:0)
```

//

there should be 2 colors the selected & unSelected

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = .green
self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .blue
```

You should use `insertSublayer` in cases where you have to set alpha of color to 1 , in your case you can use `addSublayer` but to show the buttons you need to set the alpha of both colors of the gradient to be say 0.5 or something that show UI elements (which are layers also) behind it

Comment: Wow, that worked fine!! and one question, how should I change the color of the buttons which are not selected?

Comment: how should I change the navigation controller's color ? I want it to be the same as this one